# Replace a character in a specific URL parameter

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace the `/` separator in the value of URL `param1` parameter  with `\`, but I can't figure how to do it without changing it for all parameters like `param2`

For example

```
param1=abc/def/123&param2=abc/def/123
```

I would like to become

```
param1=abc\def\123&param2=abc/def/123
```

Here is a [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/ngLYIz/2)

Comment: Replace `(param1=.+?)\/` with ``\1\\``? https://regex101.com/r/2RRLKf/1

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I'm don't understand your solution.  It only replaces the first slash, but not the second one and there could be mutiple ones. Here is the [updated example](https://regex101.com/r/ngLYIz/3)

Comment: My bad, I thought you only wanted to replace the first one. What programming language or regex flavor are you using?

Comment: I will do this in Java 1.6, and I was wandering if I can avoid iterating the parameters and their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split this in 2 simple steps. First dig out "param1=..." substring with regexp, and then just replace "/" with "\" in it. Here's an example in JavaScript:

```js
var str = "param1=qwe/qwe/wer&param2=qd/fs/aw";
var match = str.match(/^(.*)(param1=[a-z\/0-9_]+\b)(.*)$/);
var result = match[1] + match[2].replace(/\//g, "\\") + match[3];
console.log(str, result);
```